# What kind of widget is this?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to make a widget exactly like this,

[image: http://i50.tinypic.com/a476lu.png]

I want mine to be exactly the same (same font, picture, ect). Does anyone know how I can do this? I think it is a wx.ListCtrl but I cant find an example on how to make it look like this.

Can you provide me an example on how to make this widget?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a report list. Don't forget to keep a reference to the image list yourself since the bindings are stupid and don't incref it when you assign it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If the widget brings up different panels when you click on the image, then it's probably a Listbook, not a ListCtrl. Plus those are images from the wxPython demo for the Listbook AND the Toolbook AND the Treebook demos, so I'm guessing it's one of those.